# Triangles angles from the ratio of its sides

Tags: geometry, trigonometry

How do I determine the angles of a triangle if I know the ratio of its sides?

I tried Law of sines but it didn't get me anywhere...

Comment: If $a,b,c$ are the sides, then you know $a/c,b/c$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose the first side of triangle is $a$, and other sides are $ka$ and $ma$, where $k$,$m$ $\in R$.
So you could use $\cos$-Theorem.